# <apex:inputSecret> auto populate is not working?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I want to display password value as secret and it need to be auto populate from salesforce without passing manually.
   I can able to display username  but password field display empty.

Anyone help me where should i need to be modify.

### Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Login__c" extensions="Test" >
apex:form>

<apex:inputField value="{!login.Username__c}" style="width:100px"/><br/>

<apex:inputSecret value="{!login.Password__c}"/>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

### Apex class :

```
public with sharing class Test{

    public Login__c login{get;set;}

    public Test(ApexPages.StandardController controller){ 

        this.login = (Login__c)controller.getRecord();        
        login =[SELECT id,Name,Username__c,Password__c,URL__c,Session__c FROM Login__c];          

    }
```

Comment: Please use the `{}` tool, or select and press Ctrl-K, to format your code. I've done this for you this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A password should **never** be sent from the server to the client in plaintext. This is a major application security hole. The password should not be stored on the server in plaintext, either; ideally, the password should be stored only in hashed and salted form.

Storing and returning passwords exposes you to serious security vulnerabilities at multiple layers of your application. It's best to either delegate login and privilege enforcement to Salesforce or to do your implementation very, very carefully.

### Specific Notes

`<apex:inputSecret>` by default doesn't populate an existing value from the server, presumably for the very reason that it's not secure to do so. This is easily demonstrated with a simple Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form >
        Name is {! Account.Name }<br />
        <apex:inputSecret value="{! Account.Name }" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Load it with an Account and you'll see, even if you inspect the input element in browser debug, that there is no value associated with the `inputSecret` component, although the name is rendered to the page.

**Edit** - see Vijay's excellent answer if you want to change this behavior, although I really suggest not doing so.

This query is not needed and is incorrect:

```
    login =[SELECT id,Name,Username__c,Password__c,URL__c,Session__c FROM Login__c];
```

Your controller already has a reference to the relevant sObject via the standard controller. This query will throw a `QueryException` if more than one record is present in `Login__c`. If you added `LIMIT 1` to allow you to assign it to an sObject variable, you would get back a *random* `Login__c` object, compounding the security problems with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prepopulate the password with the mask, you will have to use `redisplay`  attribute of `<apex:inputSecret>`.

This above mentioned attribute if set to `true` displays the value from controller in **masked** form and if it's not set, it defaults to `false`  and does not display anything.

Excerpt from Salesforce documentation on [`inputSecret`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputSecret.htm)

> redisplay : A Boolean value that specifies whether a previously
>   entered password is rendered in this form. If set to true, the
>   previously entered value is displayed with its mask. If not specified,
>   this value defaults to false.

So your your visualforce code should be

```
<apex:inputSecret value="{!login.Password__c}" redisplay="true"/>
```

And as mentioned by David, you don't have to query on the `Login__c` object as the values you need would be available via standard controller's instance.

Comment: tq vijay it works fine now

Comment: Glad to help you!!